# Bind action mailer smtp setting from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

Right now i have set my all smtp setting in environment.rb file.

I have stored my all setting in database.

I want to bind smtp setting from my model.

How may i dynamically bind those settings from model ?

Comment: SMTP settings can be set dynamically in the model. I also came across this because gmail only allows 500 emails per day. I found a few solutions but the one that worked best is the first


http://blog.honustudios.com/2009/04/multiple-gmail-accounts-in-rails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

   UserMailer.smtp_settings = {
      :tls            => Model.find_by_column_name("SMTP_TLS").column_name,
      :address        => Model.find_by_column_name("SMTP_ADDRESS").column_name,
      :port           => Model.find_by_column_name("SMTP_PORT").column_name,
      :domain         => Model.find_by_column_name("SMTP_DOMAIN").column_name
   }

  def mail_example(to_address,subject,options={})
    sender(to_address,subject,options)
  end

  def sender(to_address,subject,options)
    recipients to_address
    from Model.find_by_column_name("SMTP_FROM_ADDRESS").column_name
    subject subject
    sent_on Time.now
    body options
  end
end
```

I have create a common sender function.
May be that will help.

Answer (score 4):

WARNING: smtp_settings is a class variable and not instance variable. If the server is forking a different ruby process for each user request then the above method will work. If a new process is not forked but instead a thread is created per user request than there may be race condition.